# How to get alert message before redirect a page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using vs 2010. I need to display the message to user and redirect the page.

I use the below line.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "<script> alert('User details saved sucessfully');window.open('frmDisplayUsers.aspx');</script>", true);
```

But I didn't get the alert message and the page was directly redirected.

How to get alert message?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your code is opening window but your asking for a redirect, below is an example of a redirect:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
"alert", 
"alert('User details saved sucessfully');window.location ='frmDisplayUsers.aspx';", 
true);
```

Comment: If there is a session object.  I believe it would go away with this method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", " alert('User details saved sucessfully'); window.open('frmDisplayUsers.aspx');", true);
```

Please note that I have removed the script tags as the last parameter true means you must not use the script tag.

This code worked for me. If you have any problem let me know. In addition you can use `setTimeout` to delay the window open that might not be a very bad choice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put in .CS file, just try this:

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + msg +"');window.location ='"+ aspx +"';", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, if possible, is to put the code into the OnClientClick.

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick=" alert('blah?');" runat="server" />
```

The problem with putting it into a startupscript is that the startupscript is run on postback, not real time. The redirect will happen before the postback. (possibly)

The other solution of course is to put the redirect into the startupscript code.

The page will post back, the script will run and then it will redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Working with UpdatePanel then You have to use this :
It is work with Update Panel.

```
 var message = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("Bill No. : " + BillNo + " successfully generated.");
            var script = string.Format("alert({0});window.location ='ChhallanPrint.aspx';", message);
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "", script, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to Login page after password updated alert message

```
Dim MyScript As String = "alert('Password Updated Successfully!. Please Login Again!'); window.location = '../Login.aspx';"
```

And if your intent is to framebust your page into the top level, because
your page may be inside a frame that is itself inside a frame.

```
Dim MyScript As String = "alert('Password Updated Successfully!. Please Login Again!');window.top.location='../Logout.aspx';"
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "MyScript", MyScript, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't use those methods successfully.
I use `Server.Transfer()` instead.

Example: (from [Redirecting Another Page after Messagebox - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/377557/Redirecting-Another-Page-after-Messagebox))

```cs
Response.Write("<script>alert('User details saved successfully');</script>");
Server.Transfer("frmDisplayUser.aspx");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Asking for a redirect page, below is an example of a redirect:

```
   string page = "Login.aspx";
        string myStringVariable = "Password Update!";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');Response.Redirect('"+ page +"' );", true);
```