# Redirect page after showing a message using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am simply trying to show message first then redirect the user to another page.  The issue i am having is that it is not showing the message first but it is redirecting the page right a way. 
Here is my code

```
if (some condition == true)
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    message = "Success.  Please check your email.  Thanks.";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);

    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get alert message before redirect a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570766/how-to-get-alert-message-before-redirect-a-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve your result is doing it asynchronously with Javascript (client-side).

If you want do it server-side, here is an example:

```
protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "You will now be redirected to YOUR Page.";
    string url = "http://www.yourpage.com/";
    string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
    script += message;
    script += "');";
    script += "window.location = '";
    script += url;
    script += "'; }";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", script, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your code redirects from server-side, even before that script reaches the client browser. You should remove that redirect and modify your javascript so that the redirect is done at the client side AFTER that message is displayed.

EDIT: You should definitely check on [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/01/14/asp-net-page-life-cycle-diagram.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're doing two things:

1. Adding a script to the output that is sent to the browser that presents a JavaScript alert.
2. Using [`Response.Redirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx) to trigger an [HTTP 302 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

The latter (2) means that (1) doesn't actually do anything. To achieve what you want here, you could send a script down using RegisterStartupScript like:

```
alert('Message');
window.location.href = 'login.aspx';
```

So you'd *remove* the `Response.Redirect` line and use:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "'); window.location.href = 'login.aspx'", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer in C#. Just give the user enough time to read the message, then redirect your user to your desired page.

This thread has a good example in using the timer: [how to use Timer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094008/how-to-use-timer-in-c-sharp)