# How to exit from a method manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, terminate

I have a query which returns a DataSet. After that I check whether records are available or not. If no records available I want to display error message, exit from the process and redirect to another page. Methods available in below the exiting method  should not execute.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
ds = dba.loadEmpInfo(number, searchType, department);
        string appNumber = "";
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            appNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ref_no"].ToString();
            workDS = dba.workExp(appNumber, searchType);
        }
        else
        {
            WebMsgBox.Show("No Record relevant to this app number are available");

        }
```

Comment: use the `return` keyword

Comment: Exit which process? What type of application is this?

Comment: I tried. But didn't worked

Comment: `Application.Exit();`

Comment: What is this? WinForms? Console? ASP? Can you show more of the method?

Comment: `Exit Sub` after your MsgBox ?

Comment: @nbadaud This isn't VB

Comment: If it's not a winroms application reopen question

Comment: It is a web application

Comment: I think "redirect to another page" makes it clear it isn't a Winforms question.

Comment: Look at this: [How to get alert message before redirect a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570766/how-to-get-alert-message-before-redirect-a-page)

Comment: @TiMSchmelter, As in the code within the else part I want to display an error message, redirect to another page and finally to exit from the method (avoid the execution of other methods below this method)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show Alert message from code behind use below syntax,
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Control control, Type type,string key, string script,bool addScriptTags);

i.e, in the else part
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Alert",
   "alert('No Record relevant to this app number are available!');", true);
// Now Re-direct to the next page as you wish
Response.Redirect("yourPage.aspx");
}

Comment: if you find this answer relevant to your question, kindly Upvote :)

Comment: This doesn't redirect to the page I want

Comment: The page you wish to Redirect is in same folder or its in different folder?