# Redirect to homepage after alert message is closed?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a javascript alert  as part of a button click event and i want to redirect to the homepage after the alert is clicked.

is this possible?

This is my alert

```
string script = @
    "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Booking Complete! Thank you for choosing Euro-City-Tours');
    </script>";

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get alert message before redirect a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570766/how-to-get-alert-message-before-redirect-a-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the identation. In my opinion this reads better:

```
string script = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Booking Complete! Thank you for choosing Euro-City-Tours');
                window.location.href = ""http://stackoverflow.com"";
                </script>";

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to another page, you can use:

window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";

Thanks.,

Answer (score 1):

You should do this, because alert is a dialog, and execute the code after it close.

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">

alert('Booking Complete! Thank you for choosing Euro-City-Tours');
window.location.replace('my home page url');

</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

just to make it a little fancy and to give the user a chance to read and close the alert before redirecting.

```
 var delay = 5000;
 setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
             }, delay); 
 alert("You will be redirected to Home Page after 5 seconds");
```

the alert will execute anyway.

Comment: I mean you need a delay so the user have a chance to read and close the alert before redirecting to your home page.

Answer (score 0):

Add the redirect after the `alert()`, the script will halt until the alert is clicked away:

```
alert('Hello!');
window.location = 'somewhere.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `confirm` function provided it is an alert box.
What happens here is `window.location` will redirect your current page to the specified url

```
var clickedBtn=confirm("Alert box");
if (clickedBtn==true) {
  //pressed ok. Redirect to url
  window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
} else {
  //pressed cancel
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple

```
window.location.href = "/Home";
```

does the tricks